# Get Sharepoint Online files with Azure Functions

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-functions, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to use Azure Functions to get Sharepoint files URLs in order to download them on a Portal.

I'm working on Dynamics 365 CRM and Portals, with an Online Sharepoint and an Azure account.

Could you help me finding how to access Sharepoint files through the Azure Functions ?

Thanks for your help.

Asconoid

Comment: hve you think about using logic app ???

Answer (score 1):

I would personaly make use of the Sharepoint REST API's. Make sure to think about the security aspect of this kind of function, since you might be creating a huge security and trust issue if you decide to use a service principal to access those sharepoint documents without validation of the client who is calling the function.

[Sharepoint REST API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Steven, I'll give it a go !